how to add tooltip on x axis labels - on highchart
I have a chart that its options config looks like that:
this.chartOptions = {
{
    "responsive": {
        "rules": [
            {
                "condition": {
                    "maxWidth": 500
                },
                "_id": "highcharts-7kdse7e-57"
            }
        ]
    },
    "chart": {
        "type": "line",
        "style": {
            "cursor": "pointer"
        },
        "zooming": {
            "type": "x"
        }
    },
    "title": {
        "text": "",
        "align": "left"
    },
    "subtitle": {
        "text": "",
        "align": "left"
    },
    "credits": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "legend": {
        "enabled": false
    },
    "plotOptions": {
        "area": {
            "marker": {
                "radius": 2
            },
            "lineWidth": 1,
            "color": {
                "linearGradient": {
                    "x1": 0,
                    "y1": 0,
                    "x2": 0,
                    "y2": 1
                },
                "stops": [
                    [
                        0.5,
                        "#95AAB8"
                    ],
                    [
                        1,
                        "#F3F6F7"
                    ]
                ]
            },
            "states": {
                "hover": {
                    "lineWidth": 1
                }
            },
            "threshold": null
        }
    },
    "series": [
        {
            "data": [
                [
                    1709164800000,
                    0
                ],
                [
                    1709251200000,
                    49.43333435058594
                ],
                [
                    1709337600000,
                    49.343135833740234
                ],
                [
                    1709424000000,
                    54.70000076293945
                ]
            ],
            "lineColor": "#7E97A8",
            "name": "",
            "type": "area"
        }
    ],
    "exporting": {
        "buttons": {
            "contextButton": {
                "enabled": false
            }
        }
    },
    "xAxis": {
        "type": "datetime",
        "lineColor": "#C3C5C9",
        "labels": {}
    },
    "yAxis": {
        "title": {
            "text": ""
        },
        "labels": {
            "style": {
                "color": "#3F5C69"
            }
        }
    },
    "tooltip": {}
}
};

I looked online and I did not find a working solution.
I need that the tooltip will appear over the labels of the x axis dynamically.
and I already have other tooltip over that chart that need to work in parallel.
what can I do to solve that?
I tried everything

In Highcharts, there are no built-in events for adding tooltips to axis labels. However, there is a custom-events plugin that allows you to add hover events to the axis labels. With this plugin, you can easily render tooltips when users hover over the labels.
Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-ppt2px?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts
Docs: https://blacklabel.github.io/custom_events/

thank you but there is a small problem with the demo you gave me:

it does not have mouse out event.
when I tried it on my code the tooltip always appeared at the top of the chart and not at the label itself.


Here's a demo with mouseOut event too: https://stackblitz.com/edit/highcharts-angular-line-dpfvin?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts the position of the tooltip is correct in the demo I sent. If you're having any problems please feel free to share your demo with me.
